# Netmiko SSH connect problem in cisco devices

Tags: python, ssh, syntax-error, f-string, netmiko

Program:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

iosv_l2 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip':   '192.168.122.50',
    'username': 'sagar',
    'password': 'sagar',

}

net_connect =ConnectHandler(**iosv_l2)
output =net_connect.send_command('show ip int brief')
print(output)

config_commands = [ 'int loop 0', 'ip addre 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0']
output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
print (output)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netmiko1", line 3, in <module>
    from netmiko import ConnectHandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from netmiko.ssh_dispatcher import ConnectHandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 2, in <module>
    from netmiko.a10 import A10SSH
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko/a10/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from netmiko.a10.a10_ssh import A10SSH
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko/a10/a10_ssh.py", line 3, in <module>
    from netmiko.cisco_base_connection import CiscoSSHConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko/cisco_base_connection.py", line 143
    msg = f"Login failed: {self.host}"
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Netmiko 3.x.x requires Python 3.6+ so you will need to upgrade your Python version to that (or downgrade to Netmiko 2.4.2).

Answer (score 0):

This module uses [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), which were only added to Python in version 3.6. To fix this, upgrade Python to 3.6 or later. You are currently using 2.7.

The [3.0.0 update](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/releases) to Netmiko removed all support for Python 2.7. In order to continue using Python 2.7, you'll have to downgrade to version 2.4.2.